# Time and Space Complexity of Average

Tags: time, big-o, space-complexity

I have an equation that is as such
`cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / ++count;`
but then the count can be limited by the window size if the count is greater than or equal to the window size so the equation has a potential to become
`cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / windowSize;` 
The windowSize is constant.  By my observation of this area, is O(n) then to O(1) when it hits the window size.
Also the space complexity I am guessing is O(n) as well.

the whole method is such:

```
 double[] CMA(int windowSize, double[] values)
        {
            //size of array determined by user
            double[] cValues = new double[values.Length];
            //index
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var d in values)
            {
                if (count >= windowSize)
                {
                    cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / windowSize;
                }
                else if (count < windowSize)
                {
                    cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / ++count;
                }

            }

            return cValues;
        }
```

The values can be any types of doubles, negative or positive.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I'm unsure what your `windowSize`, `d` and `i` is. Your algorithm looks like one that reaches its saturation point very quickly, but I need to know more in order to properly answer.

Comment: Oh so sorry:  int i = 0;
                foreach (var d in values).  d is an item in a collection (an array of doubles) I will update it

Comment: Are the doubles always higher than 1? Or always higher than 0? Can they be negatives? Can you show sample examples?

Comment: Yes they can be higher than one.  They can be negative.  They can be decimals and negative decimals.  The windowSize cannot be 0.

Comment: CMA (5, [0, 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 0.5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is that since we can have negatives, it is possible that we never surpass `windowSize`, hence reaching `count` is a perfectly possible scenario, so, in time this is O(n). In terms of space complexity, the whole function has O(n) as you have correctly understood it, but the actual algorithm, that is, the

```
            foreach (var d in values)
            {
                if (count >= windowSize)
                {
                    cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / windowSize;
                }
                else if (count < windowSize)
                {
                    cValues[i++] = (sum += d) / ++count;
                }

            }
```

part does not allocate new elements. The initialization phase is responsible for your whole space complexity.

Comment: Does it go down to O(1) when it hits the windowSize?

Comment: @GreenArrow it's the other way around: When it goes down to O(1), then it hits the `windowSize`. It is possible that hundreds of millions of items are processed before we reach the limitations. So, what we know is that the O(1) case means **early** reach to `windowSize`.

Comment: Oh cool.  That is what I thought but I could not articulate it.  All I could think of as you had said it can go very large very quickly and I thought of exponential in terms of plain math speak, but I knew it was not O(C^N).

Comment: @GreenArrow don't worry, in time you will be able to articulate these details. That ability comes with experience.